# How to debug this error? "Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: c#

here's the code

```
    private void btngetage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string a = txtAge.Text;
            DateTime bday = new DateTime(int.Parse(txtbday.Text));
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

            int age = today.Year - bday.Year;
            if (bday > today.AddYears(-age))
                age--;
            txtAge.Text = age.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: check the value of `txtbday.Text`.

Comment: why on earth you parse into `int` first?

Comment: What is the value of `txtbday.Text`?  Is it what you intended it to be?  What result did you expect, given that *exact* input?

Comment: you are parsing int to datetime?

Comment: The debugger is your friend. Unless you are using an IDE without a reasonable debugger, you have no excuse not to use it.

Comment: You should use the debugger to find the exact line of the error, although I'm pretty sure its where you are parsing an `int` to `DateTime`, that's just not normal, as no one should be expected to enter a birthdate as an integer.

Answer (score 4):

When you do stuff like this,

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

you make debugging harder on yourself. Now, rather than stopping on the line that contains the error, the debugger isn't going to stop at all. It's just going to show your message box and move on because you've already handled the error.

Don't use catch blocks except to catch exceptions that you're expecting and are going to handle. And as a corollary to that, never catch the base `Exception` class, since it has a lot of subclasses that you will never able to handle (like `OutOfMemoryException`). Always catch specific, derived exceptions.

Or don't catch any exceptions at all. There is a global unhandled exception handler that you can use if necessary. By default, it will display an alert that contains information about the exception. (Which is essentially the same thing that the above code does, except much better.)

Once you take that worthless catch block out, the debugger will stop on this line:

```
DateTime bday = new DateTime(int.Parse(txtbday.Text));
```

It will tell you that the `int.Parse` method is throwing an exception and which type of exception it is. You'll learn that the input (`txtbday.Text`) is not a valid integer, and therefore cannot be converted to an integer.

You could solve this by catching `FormatException` and handling the error, but there's no reason to do that, since there is a `TryParse` method provided that doesn't throw any exceptions. Instead, it returns a bool that indicates success or failure. Test that with an if statement. If the string cannot be parsed, use an [`ErrorProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx) component to alert the user of the problem with the string they entered.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse an invalid integer here:

```
int.Parse(txtbday.Text)
```

Try to use this instead

```
DateTime.Parse(txtbday.Text)
```

To prevent the exception, it's better to use `DateTime.TryParse` method:

```
DateTime bday;
if (DateTime.TryParse(txtbday.Text, out bday))
{
    int age = today.Year - bday.Year;
    if (bday > today.AddYears(-age))
        age--;
    txtAge.Text = age.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
DateTime bday = new DateTime(int.Parse(txtbday.Text));
```

You should do this, though it is all i can get from your question.

```
DateTime bday;
if(DateTime.TryParse(txtbday.Text.Trim(),out bday))
{
    //your rest of code
}
```

**Note:** *Textbox* control should be used for taking text input. For datetime input change the control to **date time picker**. You won't have to do any parsing .